# Library linking not working when CMake single build

Tags: cmake

using CMake I want to build in each directory A, B, and C.

The project structure is as follows:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── a.cpp
├── B
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── src
│       └── b.cpp
├── common
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── common.h
│   └── src
│       └── common.cpp
└── C
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── src
        └── c.cpp
```

Create a library in the Common directory and install the created library.

common/CmakeLists.txt :

```
set(COMMON_LIB_NAME CommonTemp)
set(SRC_CODE
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/common.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/common.cpp
)

add_library (${COMMON_LIB_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_CODE})

install(TARGETS ${COMMON_LIB_NAME} DESTINATION ~/tempDir/lib)
```

I want to link the generated library to directory A.
a.cpp requires common.h.

A/CMakeLists.txt:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(ServiceA src/a.cpp)

target_include_directories (
    ServiceA PUBLIC
    include
)

target_sources (
    ServiceA PRIVATE
    src/a.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(
    ServiceA PUBLIC
    ${COMMON_LIB_NAME} #### Location considered to be a problem
)

install(TARGETS ServiceA DESTINATION ~/tempDir/bin/A)
```

An error message occurs saying that common.h cannot be included.

My guess is that the ${COMMON_LIB_NAME} variable is defined in CMakeLists.txt in another directory, so it is expected that it cannot be linked.
But even if I put CommonTemp , the value of the variable, it says that common.h cannot be found.

How can I link library links even if I build CMake individually in each directory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In common/CmakeLists.txt.

You need to include the headers in `target_include_directores`.

```
target_include_directories(
        ${COMMON_LIB_NAME} PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    )
```

No need to mention it in `add_library`

In A/CMakeLists.txt. Include path is not correct.

```
target_include_directories(
    ServiceA PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<path to common>/include
)
```

For linking the library you have to mention the correct library path otherwise it will fail

```
target_link_libraries(
    ServiceA PUBLIC
    ${COMMON_LIB_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/<path to tempDir>/lib
)
```

Comment: Don't put absolute paths to a library in a temp directory in the user's home folder in the CMakeLists.txt anywhere, but especially not in `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: thank you. Your comment was a hint. The problem was solved by including the content included in target_include_directories in Common/CMakeLists.txt in A/CMakeLists.txt as well.
In addition, the library path of Common is set in target_link_directories, and target_link_libraries (ServiceA PUBLIC
-lCommonTemp)
Link was successful Thank you so much!